# DragonRise Gamepad not working on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, usb, gamepad, joystick

I bought a generic DragonRise Gamepad online. but I cannot get it working on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
Whilst it is properly detected:

```
$ lsusb 
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 0079:0006 DragonRise Inc. PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad
```

and:

```
$ dmesg
[62691.631653] usb 3-4: new low-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[62691.787503] usb 3-4: New USB device found, idVendor=0079, idProduct=0006, bcdDevice= 1.01
[62691.787507] usb 3-4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[62691.787510] usb 3-4: Product: Generic USB Joystick
[62691.787512] usb 3-4: Manufacturer: NoName
[62692.383603] input: NoName Generic USB Joystick as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-4/3-4:1.0/0003:0079:0006.0007/input/input29
[62692.447967] dragonrise 0003:0079:0006.0007: input,hidraw5: USB HID v1.01 Gamepad [NoName Generic USB Joystick] on usb-0000:00:14.0-4/input0
[62692.447969] dragonrise 0003:0079:0006.0007: no output reports found
[62692.447969] dragonrise 0003:0079:0006.0007: force feedback init failed
```

But the device is not available:

```
cat /proc/bus/input/devices
[Nothing found about my gamepad]
```

and ls shows nothing too: (no "js0")

```
$ ls /dev/input/
by-id    event0  event10  event12  event14  event16  event18  event2  event4  event6  event8  mice    mouse1
by-path  event1  event11  event13  event15  event17  event19  event3  event5  event7  event9  mouse0  mouse2
```

Plus tools do not find the gamepad when launched. I have installed: "xserver-xorg-input-joystick" , "joystick" (tried jscal) , "modprobe xpad" hasn't helped , "gamepad-tool" and "qjoypad" have not found it.

FYI: I am on Linux 5.10:

```
$ uname -r
5.10.0-1023-oem
```

FYI: The device is connected (red light) obviously as it is detected. and the USB A connection is done via an original Dell USB-C to USB-A 3.0 adapter, as I only have USB-C ports (could it be the issue?).

FYI: I have read many posts about this gamepad , but haven't found anything working.

FYI: [Here is the product link](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/123869199151)

Thanks for reading this,

Answer (score 0):

Lots of generic USB gamepads use the same IDs (0079:0006) but have different button layouts or support different features which makes driver support difficult. If you can link to a photo or product page for your gamepad it will make it easier for other users to figure out which device you have.

The `dmesg` output suggests it tried to load the [dragonrise driver](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/hid/hid-dr.c) but hit an error. The dragonrise driver is intended for knockoff Playstation controllers:

```
/*
 * Force feedback support for DragonRise Inc. game controllers
 *
 * From what I have gathered, these devices are mass produced in China and are
 * distributed under several vendors. They often share the same design as
 * the original PlayStation DualShock controller.
 *
 * 0079:0006 "DragonRise Inc.   Generic   USB  Joystick  "
 *  - tested with a Tesun USB-703 game controller.
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 Richard Walmsley <richwalm@gmail.com>
 */
```

From the `dmesg` error it seems like your device doesn't have any rumble support. If it did, the driver should have found at least one output report. If your gamepad doesn't have rumble it probably doesn't even need a special driver and can use the default hid-input driver.

Try unloading the `dragonrise` kernel module and reconnecting the gamepad.

Comment: Hi @nondebug and thanks for your reply. [Here is where I bought it](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/123869199151). Hope it helps. Give me a shout if you need pictures of a better quality. I'll also try your excellent suggestion and get back to you guys.