# Configure a joystick in ubunntu 20.04

Tags: gamepad

I have a `0079-0006-DragonRaise Inc Generic USB Joystick`. It is being recognised by my ubuntu 20.40. On testing with `jstest-gtk` I found a very odd problem

- BUTTON_TRIGGER is not recognised
- Axis 2 is also invoking Buttons 0 and 2 in addition to their original actions
- Axis 3 is just invoking Buttons 1 and 3
- BASE buttons are invoking Axises 0 and 1

Is this a problem with my drivers?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with my Gamepad. My drivers are fine.

Answer (score 0):

Hardware with vendor ID 0x0079 and product ID 0x0006 is usually a generic USB HID gamepad (sometimes called ["PC TWIN SHOCK Gamepad"](https://devicehunt.com/view/type/usb/vendor/0079/device/0006)), often with DualShock 2 styling but sometimes with a completely different form factor like [this arcade joystick thing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1337158/dragonrise-gamepad-not-working-on-ubuntu-20-04/1337359?noredirect=1#comment2283158_1337359). Since the product can't be uniquely identified from the device IDs, it would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a link to a product page showing an image of the device you're trying to use.

HID gamepads technically don't need a driver, but the inputs may not be correctly mapped in games if they don't use the same keycodes described in the [Linux Gamepad Specification](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/input/gamepad.html). Devices with IDs 0076:0006 are handled in the [dragonrise module](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/55fcd4493da5ac8a0f7a0b3b5ae8448aee2041bb/drivers/hid/hid-dr.c), which seems to do some weird remapping that might cause the behavior you're seeing.

You might have some luck disabling the dragonrise module so the gamepad is handled by the default HID gamepad driver. Force feedback probably won't work but the mapping might be more correct.